# Trying to figure out the CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, cardlayout

I'm trying to work out how to use the CardLayout but I keep getting "wrong parent for CardLayout" errors and such. I've never used CardLayout before and I can't seem to find a lot online. I just need to be able to switch between two panels on the frame. Thanks for any help. Here is my current code:

```
    Frame f = new Frame();
    CardLayout cardL = new CardLayout();
    JPanel cards = new JPanel(cardL);
    f.add(cards);
    StartPanel sp = new StartPanel();
    OtherPanel op = new OtherPanel();
    cards.add(sp, "Start");
    cards.add(op, "Other");

    cardL.show(sp, "Start");

    f.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: [It's Online](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
cardL.show(sp, "Start");
```

to

```
cardL.show(cards, "Start");
```

As the [CardLayout API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) will tell you, the first parameter of the `show(...)` method should be a reference to the container that uses the CardLayout.

Also:

- Avoid mixing AWT (Frame) and Swing (JPanel). Instead use just Swing.
- Safest to use String constants for your CardLayout keys. This way you avoid pernicious spelling and capitalization errors.
- For similar errors, go to the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html) first before coming here. The solutions are often found there, and learning to do this is a good habit to get into.